# mod_rewrite to ssl not working for example.com but does for example.com/index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

NOTE: config and error updated to be clearer.

I have the following .htaccess for my site running apach 2.4 on Ubuntu:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

- If I go to http://example2.com, `http://www.example2.com or`http://www.example1.com`it redirects to`https`
- if I go to `http://example1.com` it stays as http.

Is there something I am missing so that it will redirect with just the base `/` url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example2.com
```

You need to add `?` to make the `www.` optional:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2.com
```

Comment: that breaks it all.  where going to `example.(com|net)/index.html` or `www.example.(com|net)/index.html` redirected to `https`, now it does not.  it is the same as going to `example.(com|net)` and www.example.(com|net)`  it stays as `http`

Comment: actually looking now, my example in OP gets it working for when I include www but fails if I omit it.  Is there away to tell it to do it for either www.example.xxx and example.xxx?

Comment: actually i realized my redacting of addresses was not good. It's `example1.com`  and `example2.com`

Comment: brilliant, that was the problem!